# Wordpress. How to get the custom post_type count in taxonomy.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.7, I have custom taxonomies and custom post_type's (song, poem). In `taxonomy.php` template I want the count of each post_type posts.

I have the below code which gives me the total count of queried object / term:

```
// current term
$term = get_queried_object();
// total posts from the queried term
$get_posts = get_term($term->term_id, $term->taxonomy);
// total posts count in current term
$total_post_count = $get_posts->count;
```

How can I get the total songs and total poems count in the current term?

Comment: What is your post_type name? What is your taxonomy name? in which terms posts you want to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) and [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters). check code below.

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'your-post-type-name',
    'post_status'    => 'publish', // get only publish posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // get all posts
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term->term_id
        )
    )
);

$AllPostByTerms = new WP_Query( $args );

echo $AllpostByTerms->post_count;
```

Comment: I have created two different queries for each post_type (song, poem), tested, working.

Any possibility to optimize the code by write the overall query first and just change the `post_type` argument in a single line for each post_type to get that post_type count?