# WordPress. How to get multiple custom post_type total posts count in taxonomy.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

In my WordPress v5.7 `taxonomy.php` template, I have this below code to get a custom `post_type` total posts count. (Code as suggested here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66751447/3725816).

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'your-post-type-name',
    'post_status'    => 'publish', // get only publish posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // get all posts
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term->term_id
        )
    )
);

$AllPostByTerms = new WP_Query( $args );

echo $AllpostByTerms->post_count;
```

Now that I have multiple (many) custom post_type's in my WordPress.

Instead of repeating the same code for each post_type in `taxonomy.php` template, is there a way I can get the total posts count of each custom `post_type` in a single function / query?

---

**EDIT** (Desired result):

I want each custom post_type total posts counts.

Example:

```
post-type1 = 10,
post-type-name2 = 20,
post-type-name3 = 30
```

Comment: I don’t think it makes that much sense to try and get this using the normal WP_Query methodology. That’s not made to perform this kind of query, with individual grouping and counting. Plus, with the above, you are still _fetching_ all the post data, even though you are only interested in the count. This is a use case for a custom written query IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just stumbled upon your question and not sure if you're still interested to see an answer or not, but i'll add my answer for future reference, just in case somebody needs it.

So, there are multiple ways that you could achieve what you're looking for! However there are certain things that you didn't mention in your question!

For example, when counting "total post counts" you didn't mention which post status you're referring to!

> - Counting published posts?
> - Counting draft posts?
> - Counting pending posts?
> - Counting trashed posts?
> - Counting future posts?
> - Counting private posts?

Another thing that is not clear in your question, is the "type of posts" you're interested to count!

For example, in addition to your custom-post-type-1, custom-post-type-2, custom-post-type-3, wordpress has its own "built-in" post types such as:

> - Post
> - Page
> - Attachment
> - Nav_menu_item
> - Revision

I'll give you my answer, feel free to customize it as needed!

Since you didn't mention which specific "post-type" you're looking for, i'm going to assume you're interested only in counting your `custom-post-type-1`, `custom-post-type-2` and `custom-post-type-3` etc. Therefore, we're going to use a wordpress function called `get_post_types` in order to dynamically get all of the custom post types we're interested in. Also, I'm going to assume, you're interested to count `all of the post statuses`. In order to do so, i'll use a wordpress function called `wp_count_posts`.

> [get_post_types<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types/)

> [wp_count_posts<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_posts/)

Now using the above functions, let's create our **magical function** that will return `a multidimentional associative array` containing the counts for each status of each custom post type!

**NO WP_QUERY NEEDED!**

```php
function your_them_counter_post_types()
{

  $args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false // This will leave out built-in post types (i.e Post, Page, Attachment, Nav_menu_item, Revision)
  );

  $output = 'names';

  $operator = 'and';

  $post_types = get_post_types($args, $output, $operator);

  $counts_array = array();

  if ($post_types) {

    if (!is_array($post_types)) {
      $post_types = (array)$post_types;
    } // just to make sure our 'foreach' doesn't throw an error!

    foreach ($post_types  as $post_type) {
      $current_post_type = wp_count_posts($post_type);
      $counts_array[$post_type] = array(
        'published' => intval($current_post_type->publish),
        'draft'     => intval($current_post_type->draft),
        'pending'   => intval($current_post_type->pending),
        'future'    => intval($current_post_type->future),
        'private'   => intval($current_post_type->private),
        'trash'     => intval($current_post_type->trash)
      );
    }
  }

  return $counts_array;
}
```

This will return a `multidimentional associative array` that looks like this:

```php
$counts_array
(
    [custom-post-type-1] => Array
        (
          [published] => 10,
          [draft] => 2,
          [pending] => 3,
          [future] => 0,
          [private] => 0,
          [trash] => 1
        ),

    [custom-post-type-2] => Array
        (
          [published] => 20,
          [draft] => 5,
          [pending] => 4,
          [future] => 0,
          [private] => 0,
          [trash] => 2
        ),

    [custom-post-type-3] => Array
        (
          [published] => 30,
          [draft] => 7,
          [pending] => 1,
          [future] => 0,
          [private] => 0,
          [trash] => 3
        )
)
```

Now that we have a **magical function**, all we need to do is to call it and loop through the returned array, like so:

```php
$posts_counts_array = your_them_counter_post_types();

foreach ($posts_counts_array as $post_type_name => $post_count_array) {
  printf(
    __('For %s: ', 'Your-Theme-text-domain'),
    $post_type_name
  );
  echo "<pre>";
  foreach ($post_count_array as $post_status_name => $post_counts) {
    printf(
      _n(
        'There is %1$s %2$s post.',
        'There are %1$s %2$s posts.',
        $post_counts,
        'Your-Theme-text-domain'
      ),
      $post_counts,
      $post_status_name
    );
    echo "<br>";
  }
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

This will return what you've asked for!

```php
For custom-post-type-1: 
There are 10 published posts.
There are 2 draft posts.
There are 3 pending posts.
There are 0 future posts.
There are 0 private posts.
There is 1 trash post.

For custom-post-type-2: 
There are 20 published posts.
There are 5 draft posts.
There is 1 pending post.
There are 0 future posts.
There are 0 private posts.
There are 2 trash posts

For custom-post-type-3: 
There are 30 published posts.
There are 7 draft posts.
There is 1 pending post.
There are 0 future posts.
There are 0 private posts.
There are 3 trash posts
```

> Note:
> I've also used the following functions to do the translations and printing the values onto the page:
> [`__`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/)
> [`_n`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/)
> [`printf`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => ['post-type-name1', 'post-type-name2', 'post-type-name3'],
'post_status'    => 'publish', // get only publish posts
'posts_per_page' => -1, // get all posts
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $term->term_id
    )
)
```

);

You can simply pass a array of all the custom post types in post type parameter

Comment: I don not want the total of all custom post_types. I want each custom post_type total posts counts.

Example= post-type1 = 10, post-type-name2 = 20, post-type-name3 = 30